# Draw lines in a loop of n times

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-graphdrawing

I'm trying to create a code that draw different lines in each iteration, but it does not work if when i used the loop index -> \x. Any suggestion? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

 \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\draw (0,0) -- (10,0) ; \draw (0,0) -- (0,10);
\draw (0,10) -- (10,10)  ; \draw (10,10) -- (10,0);
\def\mx{10}; \def\n{5};
\def\xo{5}; \def\xoo{7};
\def\yo{0}; \def\yoo{10}; 

\coordinate (p0) at (\xo,\yo);

\coordinate (p1) at (\xoo,\yoo);

\draw [red] (p0) -- (p1) ; 

\def\yn{\yoo}; 

\foreach \x in {1,..., \n} {

\draw [red] (p1) -- ((\x + 1 )*( \xoo  - \xo ) + \xo   ,10);

}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It seems that you have error in in the loop, where you nests parenthesis. Correct syntax is `\draw [red] (p1) -- ({(\x + 1)*(\xoo - \xo ) + \xo},10);`

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. How about the definition of variables? 
\def\xn{{\x*(\xoo-\xo) + \xo}};
\def\yn{ { 10 - min(10,\yoo) } };    is this writing true?

Comment: For similar calculation I will rather use `\pgfmathparse` or `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

Comment: @Zarko why is that?

Comment: hm, this is going to be chat ... :-)  (what is not desired in comments). I just express my opinion actually without knowing what is your intention with this definitions and calculations. The picture in my answer can be draw without any calculation (with more concise code). For more elaborate answer would be good idea to ask separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if you like to obtain the following picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle ++ (10,10);

\def\mx{10}; \def\n{5};
\def\xo{5}; \def\xoo{7};
\def\yo{0}; \def\yoo{10};

\coordinate (p0) at (\xo,\yo);
\coordinate (p1) at (\xoo,\yoo);

\draw [red] (p0) -- (p1) ;

\def\yn{\yoo};

\foreach \x in {1,..., \n}


   \def\xn{{\x*(\xoo-\xo) + \xo}};  % Edited, additional
   \def\yn{ { 10 - min(10,\yoo) } }; % Edited, additional

    \draw [red] (p1) -- ({(\x + 1)*(\xoo - \xo ) + \xo},10);% <-- corrected

           \draw [red] (p1) -- ({\xn},{\yn});% <---- I use this instead of % the above

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In above code I draw rectangle in simpler way and correct the error in line in the loop as I mentioned in my comment.